# How to make a textfield Editable when checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Actually, I have many checkboxes and textfields coming from database through single code. I need that when I check a particular checkbox, then a textfield in front of that checkbox to become editable. How can I do that ?

Here is my PHP code

```
<div class="my"><?php
    while ($ass = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fees_name[]" id="fee_name" value="<?php echo $ass['fees_name']; ?>" onclick='toggleReadonly(this)'>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?php echo $ass['fees_name']; ?> 
        <div style="padding:0px 10px 0px 0px; float: right;"> 
            <input id="fee_amt" class="fee_amt" type="text" placeholder="amt" name="fees_amt[]" >
        </div> <br><br><?php 
    }?>
</div>
```

and my Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fee_name').click(function() {
        $('#fee_amt').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

but it worked on only the first checkbox. Anyone can tell my what can i do for others???

Comment: Please put the code normally. Like the code is in your text editor.

Comment: IDs must be unique within an HTML document. Correct this error first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your text fields that are enabled/disabled have the same id. Try to set a different id inside the loop and in your javascript enable the one according to the checkbox that is checked.
Another way (without using ids) is to set the **data** attribute in each checkbox:

```
<div class="my">
  <?php $i = 1; ?>
  <?php while ($ass = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fees_name[]" class="fee_name" data-mycheckbox="<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $ass['fees_name']; ?>" onclick='toggleReadonly(this)'>
    <?php echo $ass['fees_name']; ?> 
    <div style="padding:0px 10px 0px 0px; float: right;"> 
        <input id="fee_amt<?php echo $i; ?>" class="fee_amt" type="text" placeholder="amt" name="fees_amt[]" >
    </div> <br><br><?php 
    $i++;
  }?>
</div>
```

And in your js script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".fee_name").click(function(event) {
    var identifier = $(this).data('mycheckbox');
    var input_identifier = "#fee_amt" + identifier; 
    $(input_identifier).prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'))
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

solution by @eyetea also solves the problem with your non-unique ids.
just in case you don't want to rely on any ids:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="fees_name\\[\\]]"').click(function() {
        $(this).next().children(':first').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

note that this sort of selecting the elements heavily relies on your dom structure and has to be changed accordingly when your html changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code what you need,

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).next().prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $(this).next().prop('disabled', true);
    }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fees_name[]">
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" /><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="fees_name[]">
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" /><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="fees_name[]" >
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="fees_name[]">
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="fees_name[]">
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4XB44/2/)

If you need to give name then you could use `input[name='fees_name[]']`as,

```
$( "input[name='fees_name[]']" ).on( "click", function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).next().prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $(this).next().prop('disabled', true);
    }

});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4XB44/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code-

```
<div class="my"><?php
$i=0;
while ($ass = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {$i++;?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fees_name[]" id="fee_name[<?php echo $i?>]" value="<?php echo $ass['fees_name']; ?>" onChange='if(this.checked){toggleReadonly(this,true);} else{toggleReadonly(this,false)}'>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <?php echo $ass['fees_name']; ?> 
    <div style="padding:0px 10px 0px 0px; float: right;">
        <input id="fee_amt[<?php echo $i?>]" class="fee_amt" type="text" placeholder="amt" name="fees_amt[]" readonly>
    </div> <br><br><?php 
}?>
```

JavaScript code

```
function toggleReadonly(chk_element, status)
{
    chk_element_no=chk_element.id.substring(chk_element.id.indexOf('[')+1, chk_element.id.indexOf(']'));
    txt_element_id="fee_amt["+chk_element_no+"]";
    if(status==true)
        document.getElementById(txt_element_id).readOnly=false;
    else
        document.getElementById(txt_element_id).readOnly=true;
}
```

check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VqD8k/)**.

Check the following **similar sample code** and **execute it**-

### 1.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function toggleReadonly(chk_element, status)
        {
            chk_element_no=chk_element.id.substring(chk_element.id.indexOf('[')+1, chk_element.id.indexOf(']'));
            txt_element_id="fee_amt["+chk_element_no+"]";
            if(status==true)
                document.getElementById(txt_element_id).readOnly=false;
            else
                document.getElementById(txt_element_id).readOnly=true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="my"><?php
    $i=0;
    while ($i++<=10) {?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fees_name[]" id="fee_name[<?php echo $i;?>]" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" onChange='if(this.checked){toggleReadonly(this,true);} else{toggleReadonly(this,false)}'>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?php echo $i; ?> 
        <div style="padding:0px 10px 0px 0px; float: right;"> 
            <input id="fee_amt[<?php echo $i;?>]" class="fee_amt" type="text" placeholder="amt" name="fees_amt[]" readonly>
        </div> <br><br><?php 
    }?>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```